# PHP autoloading class not found

Tags: php, no-framework

let me first explain what I have done to reach this point. There is a tutorial on github called no-framework here it is https://github.com/PatrickLouys/no-framework-tutorial very good tutorial! I have completed it and am now wanting to add more libraries. I have composer setup with autoloading and the file looks like this.

```
{
"name": "xxx/no-framework",
"description": "no framework",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "xxx",
        "email": "xxx@gmail.com"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.0",
    "filp/whoops": ">=1.1.2",
    "patricklouys/http": ">=1.1.0",
    "nikic/fast-route": "^0.7.0",
    "rdlowrey/auryn": "^1.1",
    "twig/twig": "~1.0",
    "illuminate/database": "*"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

}

and In my `src` folder I have made a folder called `Models` and in there a  `Books.php` and in the `Books.php` I have this

```
<?php
    class Book extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model{
        protected $table = 'books';
    }
```

and in my `Bootstrap.php` file I've included this line after requiring the composer autoloader

```
include('Database.php');
```

The `Database.php` file is also in the `src` and looks like this

```
<?php

    use \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;  

    $capsule = new Capsule; 

    $capsule->addConnection(array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'test',
        'username'  => 'test',
        'password'  => 'l4m3p455w0rd!',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => ''
    ));

    $capsule->bootEloquent();
```

And now the error. When I try to use to `Book` class by trying to `use` it in one of my controller like this

```
<?php

    namespace App\Controllers;

    use Http\Request;
    use Http\Response;
    use App\Template\Renderer;
    use App\Models\Book as Book;


    class Pages{
       private $request;
       private $response;
       private $renderer;

       public function __construct(Request $request, Response $response, Renderer $renderer){
           $this->request = $request;
           $this->response = $response;
           $this->renderer = $renderer;
       }

       public function index(){
          $book = new Book;
          $book->title = 'test';
          $book->save();

          $html = $this->renderer->render('index');
          $this->response->setContent($html);
      }
  }
```

I get an error saying "Class 'App\Models\Book' not found" I'm asuming im not autoloading something correctly, but the alias thing is there in the `composer.json` or maybe something else is wrong idk. help?
The tutorial uses a dependency injector library called Auryn, maybe I'm missing something in there? idk doubt it though.

EDIT: If i change the `use` statement to to an `include` like so
`include('../src/Models/Book.php');`
and put a `\` in front of the class instantiation like so
`$book = new \Book;`
and then it works, BUT this is clearly not the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the Composer classmap merely tells the system where to find the files for a given class. PHP still needs to know the namespaces. `Pages` is in the `App\Controllers` namespace. `Book` is not given one, so it will exist in the global namespace at `\Book`. Your `Books.php` (names of files usually match the class they contain, so would be `Book.php`) should include a namespace declaration. I suggest `namepsace App\Models;`. You could also change your `use` statement to `use \Book`.

Notice you don't **need** to alias it. It's the only `Book` class you're using so just as you did with `Request` the class can be referenced by the last segment of it's fully namespaced designation.

Comment: ahhhh I get it! I should look more into namespaces, thanks a lot!